Adding Labels to Specific Bars in a Histogram
the code i currently have generates this graph:

\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[review]{ACL2023}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
% \usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{vermillion}{RGB}{214, 39, 40}
\definecolor{bluishgreen}{RGB}{44, 160, 44}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{100, 149, 237}

\pgfplotsset{width= 7cm, compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*} [ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[ 
    group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=80pt, vertical sep=50pt},
    ybar,
    width=0.45*\textwidth, % Adjust the width of the graph
    height=6cm, % Adjust the height of the graph
    % xlabel={Models},
    ylabel={plot 1},
    ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    xlabel style={font=\small, yshift=-0.75cm},
    area style,
    xtick=data,
    ymax=2,
    % ymin=-2,
    xticklabels={A, B, C, D},
    xticklabel style={align=center, font=\scriptsize, text width=3cm}, % Adjust font size of x-axis labels and rotate them
    legend style={at={(0.5,0.15), font=\scriptsize}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    nodes near coords, % Add labels above each bar
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
] 

\nextgroupplot
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
    \addplot[fill=vermillion!20, draw=vermillion!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 0.5611510791)
        (2, 0.07194244604)
        (3, 0.4820143885)
        (4, 0.4892086331)
    };
    \addplot[fill=bluishgreen!20, draw=bluishgreen!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 0.9580152672)
        (2, 0.427480916)
        (3, 1.561068702)
        (4, 0.7595419847)
    };

    \addplot[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 1.32)
        (2, -7.12) [-7.12]
        (3, -0.48)
        (4, -0.04)
    };
    
    \legend{data1, data2, data3}

\nextgroupplot[ylabel=plot 2]
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
    \addplot[fill=vermillion!20, draw=vermillion!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 0.1851851852)
        (2, 0.4444444444)
        (3, 0.09259259259)
        (4, 0.05555555556)
    };
    
    \addplot[fill=bluishgreen!20, draw=bluishgreen!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 1.032992203)
        (2, 0.4337231969)
        (3, 0.6749512671)
        (4, 0.7071150097)
    };
    
    \addplot[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 1.164141414)
        (2, -1.886363636) [-1.89]
        (3, 0.4419191919)
        (4, 0.5025252525)
    };

    \legend{data1, data2, data3}

\nextgroupplot [ylabel=plot 3]
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
    \addplot[fill=vermillion!20, draw=vermillion!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 1)
        (2, -0.1037037037)
        (3, 0.7703703704)
        (4, 0.5407407407)
    };
    
    \addplot[fill=bluishgreen!20, draw=bluishgreen!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 0.5652173913)
        (2, -0.05217391304)
        (3, 0.5826086957)
        (4, 0.4695652174)
    };
    
    \addplot[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 1.142857143)
        (2, -5.857142857) [-5.86]
        (3, -0.2857142857)
        (4, 0.2142857143)
    };

    \legend{data1, data2, data3}

\nextgroupplot[ylabel=plot 4]
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
    \addplot[fill=vermillion!20, draw=vermillion!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 1.067307692)
        (2, 0.5096153846)
        (3, 1.899038462)
        (4, 0.6586538462)
    };
    
    \addplot[fill=bluishgreen!20, draw=bluishgreen!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 0.6689655172)
        (2, 0.1517241379)
        (3, 0.6206896552)
        (4, 0.6)
    };
    
    \addplot[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!70, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (1, 1.363636364)
        (2, -6.454545455) [-6.45]
        (3, -0.4090909091)
        (4, 0.2272727273)
    };

    \legend{data1, data2, data3}

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{graphs}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}

instead i want the following graph where the ymin is -2. and for bars smaller than -2, i want to have the bar value on top of the bars. also the left most and right most bars in the bar chart get cut off like half way through. how do i fix that?


Here is a way to do it, with some suggestions:

Preamble
As a general rule don't load what you don't need: chances increase that some packages interact in unintended ways, and you start chasing the wind.
I also suggest to compile such drawings separately using the standalone class. Include it in your main document as demonstrated here. Quite soon you'll love the flexibility gained (E.g. your fontsize problems with this drawing will be decoupled from your main document ...). // So figure etc are removed. // Also the plotwidth is probably obsolete, ore even hurting, or even overwritten (?) in your code.
Groupplot options
This was tough for me. I started commenting out all of them, and gradually uncommenting step-by-step. Here's my final result, where doing less probably results in higer benefit.
    \begin{groupplot}[ 
        group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=80pt, vertical sep=50pt},
        ybar,
%       width=0.45*\textwidth, % Adjust the width of the graph
%       height=6cm, % Adjust the height of the graph
%       % xlabel={Models},
        ylabel={plot 1},
%       ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
%       xlabel style={font=\small, yshift=-0.75cm},
%       area style,
        xtick=data,
        ymax=2,
        ymin=-2,
        xticklabels={A, B, C, D},
        enlargelimits=.25,  % <<< 25 % more space left and right
%       xticklabel style={align=center, font=\scriptsize, text width=3cm}, % Adjust font size of x-axis labels and rotate them
%       legend style={at={(0.5,0.15), font=\scriptsize}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
%       nodes near coords, % Add labels above each bar
%       nodes near coords align={vertical},
%       nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
        minor y tick num=1, % <<<
    ] 

The option you were missing is probably enlargelimits=.25, which gives some extra space left and right.
Because the y-scale was y bit thin, I added minor y tick num=1, for an extra tick.
Visual appearance
First, the legend. I put the bare standard, but honestly: the message is the same for all 4 plots. So you may want to consider to draw your own legend, e.g. below all plots using plain-Tikz (i.e. not \legend from pgfplots). I also wouldn't use it as a kind of visual strike-through as in your original.
Second, the values for negative blue bars. I'd also use plain-Tikz here and put them e.g. as shown. Again: doing less may be more.
Refactoring
This is the step of generalizing things which are used at least twice. This holds for the bar colors in your code. So let's introduce some shortcuts in the beginning:
% ~~~ refactoring colors: change in one place only ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\vmf[0]{vermillion!20}
\newcommand\vmd[0]{vermillion!70}

\newcommand\bgf[0]{bluishgreen!20}
\newcommand\bgd[0]{bluishgreen!70}

\newcommand\blf[0]{blue!20}
\newcommand\bld[0]{blue!70}

and modify the plot-line as
\addplot[fill=\bgf, draw=\bgd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates { ...

Now, if you change the colors in the beginning, all of them are updated in each and every plot or draw ...
More refactoring is perhaps not needed, which is a consequence of the pgfplots syntax. With one exception: you may absorb and replace
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1

by an other \newcommand, and again 1 change there would make it right everywhere. // The same argument holds for the \node I introduced ...
And finally you'd delete all those commented-out lines ... and your efficient code sparkles a little bit more than before.

%\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    %\usepackage[review]{ACL2023}
    %\usepackage{times}
    %\usepackage{latexsym}
    %
    %\usepackage{forest}
    %\usepackage{array}
    %\usepackage{textcomp}
    %\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    %\usepackage{booktabs}
    %\usepackage{listings}
    %\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
    %% \usepackage{extsizes}
    %
    %\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    %\usepackage{subcaption}
    %\usepackage{xcolor}
    %\usepackage{courier}
    %\usepackage{url}
    
    %\usepackage{multirow}
    %\usepackage{enumitem}
    %\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{vermillion}{RGB}{214, 39, 40}
\definecolor{bluishgreen}{RGB}{44, 160, 44}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{100, 149, 237}

% ~~~ refactoring colors: change in one place only ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\vmf[0]{vermillion!20}
\newcommand\vmd[0]{vermillion!70}

\newcommand\bgf[0]{bluishgreen!20}
\newcommand\bgd[0]{bluishgreen!70}

\newcommand\blf[0]{blue!20}
\newcommand\bld[0]{blue!70}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\pgfplotsset{%width= 7cm, 
compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure*} [ht]
%\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[ 
        group style={group size=2 by 2, horizontal sep=80pt, vertical sep=50pt},
        ybar,
%       width=0.45*\textwidth, % Adjust the width of the graph
%       height=6cm, % Adjust the height of the graph
%       % xlabel={Models},
        ylabel={plot 1},
%       ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
%       xlabel style={font=\small, yshift=-0.75cm},
%       area style,
        xtick=data,
        ymax=2,
        ymin=-2,
        xticklabels={A, B, C, D},
        enlargelimits=.25,  % <<< 25 % more space left and right
%       xticklabel style={align=center, font=\scriptsize, text width=3cm}, % Adjust font size of x-axis labels and rotate them
%       legend style={at={(0.5,0.15), font=\scriptsize}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
%       nodes near coords, % Add labels above each bar
%       nodes near coords align={vertical},
%       nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
        minor y tick num=1, % <<<
    ] 
    
    \nextgroupplot
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
        \addplot[fill=\vmf, draw=\vmd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 0.5611510791)
            (2, 0.07194244604)
            (3, 0.4820143885)
            (4, 0.4892086331)
        };
        \addplot[fill=\bgf, draw=\bgd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 0.9580152672)
            (2, 0.427480916)
            (3, 1.561068702)
            (4, 0.7595419847)
        };
    
        \addplot[fill=\blf, draw=\bld, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 1.32)
            (2, -7.12) %[-7.12]
            (3, -0.48)
            (4, -0.04)
        };
        \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:2.4,-1.8) {-7.12};
        
        \legend{data1, data2, data3}
    
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=plot 2]
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
        \addplot[fill=\vmf, draw=\vmd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 0.1851851852)
            (2, 0.4444444444)
            (3, 0.09259259259)
            (4, 0.05555555556)
        };
        
        \addplot[fill=\bgf, draw=\bgd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 1.032992203)
            (2, 0.4337231969)
            (3, 0.6749512671)
            (4, 0.7071150097)
        };
        
        \addplot[fill=\blf, draw=\bld, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 1.164141414)
            (2, -1.886363636) %[-1.89]
            (3, 0.4419191919)
            (4, 0.5025252525)
        };
    
        \legend{data1, data2, data3}
%   
    \nextgroupplot [ylabel=plot 3]
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
        \addplot[fill=\vmf, draw=\vmd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 1)
            (2, -0.1037037037)
            (3, 0.7703703704)
            (4, 0.5407407407)
        };
        
        \addplot[fill=\blf, draw=\bld, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 0.5652173913)
            (2, -0.05217391304)
            (3, 0.5826086957)
            (4, 0.4695652174)
        };
        
        \addplot[fill=\blf, draw=\bld, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 1.142857143)
            (2, -5.857142857) %[-5.86]
            (3, -0.2857142857)
            (4, 0.2142857143)
        };
        \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:2.4,-1.8) {-5.86};
    
        \legend{data1, data2, data3}
%   
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel=plot 4]
    \draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:10,1); % Draw the dotted line at y = 1
        \addplot[fill=\vmf, draw=\vmd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 1.067307692)
            (2, 0.5096153846)
            (3, 1.899038462)
            (4, 0.6586538462)
        };
        
        \addplot[fill=\bgf, draw=\bgd, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 0.6689655172)
            (2, 0.1517241379)
            (3, 0.6206896552)
            (4, 0.6)
        };
        
        \addplot[fill=\blf, draw=\bld, point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
            (1, 1.363636364)
            (2, -6.454545455) [-6.45]
            (3, -0.4090909091)
            (4, 0.2272727273)
        };
        \node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:2.4,-1.8) {-6.45};
    
        \legend{data1, data2, data3}
%   
    \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture}

%\caption{graphs}
%\end{figure*}
\end{document}

